# JQuery Autocomplete & Symfony

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

Im trying to make an autocompletion feature into my symfony app using AJAX.

When i access the route for getting users list it work perfectly :

```
["user1","user2","user3","user4","user5"]
```

But it does not affect the #form_comname, when i try to write into #form_comname nothing is loaded :(

This is my jquery script :

```
<script>
      $('#form_comname').autocomplete({
          source : function(requete, reponse){
              var motcle = $('#form_comname').val();
              var DATA = 'motcle=' + motcle;
              $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url : "{{ path('listusers') }}",
                  dataType : 'json',
                  data : DATA,

                  success : function(donnee){
                      reponse($.map(donnee, function(objet){
                          return objet;
                      }));
                  }
              });
          }
      });
  </script>
```

this is my Controller userSync :

```
public function usersyncAction(Request $request)
{
        $term = $request->request->get('motcle');

        $array= $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
            ->listeU($term);

        $response = new Response(json_encode($array));

        $response -> headers -> set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
}
```

this is my ListeU into repo :

```
public function listeU($term)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    $qb->select('c.username')
        ->where('c.username LIKE :term')
        ->setParameter('term', '%' . $term . '%');

    $arrayAss = $qb->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    // Transformer le tableau associatif en un tableau standard
    $array = array();
    foreach ($arrayAss as $data) {
        $array[] = $data['username'];
    }

    return $array;
}
```

My route file :

```
listusers:
path: /usersync
defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Security:usersync}
requirements:
    method: POST
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: I think the problem is related to the jquery part, because the rest of the code  runs well

Comment: just to clarify, did you included jquery-ui.js properly?

Comment: Yes Jquery is properly included

Comment: you mean jQuery UI, right? autocomplete is not a part of standard jquery library

Comment: Yes im talking about Jquery UI , ive included both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved this way :

```
var Link = "http://localhost/No/Web/app_dev.php/usersync";
      $( function() {
          var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhReq.open("GET", Link, false);
          xhReq.send(null);
          var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
          $( "#form_comname" ).autocomplete({
              source: jsonObject
          });
      } );
```

All i need is a route that generate a json file wich contain list users.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and js works fine as is, and does not have any mistakes.

So if you are sure, that your php works fine too, you should check these things:

- there are no errors in browser's (e.g. Chrome) DevTools->Console like `autocomplete is not a function`
- requests are being sent (check this in DevTools->Network tab)
- browser gets responses (Dev tools->Network)

If you have `autocomplete is not a function` error, check that you have included last versions of js (and jquery.min.js is included before jquery-ui.min.js). I used these:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

If requests are not being sent, check in your rendered html (DevTools->Elements) that route is generated properly (something like `url: "/listu",`).

Then check that your js code fires on input changing. You can do it on DevTools->Sources:

- choose the file with js-script on the left sidebar (e.g. `(index)`)
- find your js in the code
- click on the line number in front of line `var motcle = $('#form_comname').val();`. This will place a breakpoint on this line which will stop js execution right on this line, so you can see if code is being executed or not.

Sources tab screenshot:
[image]

If it doesn't - check if your form's input id is correct.

If request is sent, but failed, you can check the response for errors in DevTools->Network. Also you can check your logs for errors `app/logs/dev.log`.

Network tab screenshot:
[image]

If response is correct, but you don't see the result on page - check if you have included jquery-ui.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
```

Anyway I strongly recommend you to use DevTools to debug your code, check requests and responses. Also I would recommend you to use x-debug for debugging your server-side code.

Be welcome to ask any questions.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for such a help.
In the network tab i cant find request related to the autocompletion. My js script is on the layout page there is no specific file. Im using forjsrouting is it can help

Comment: @ibradev the fact that there is no request means that JS doesn't fire. I added screenshots to my answer, hope this can help

Comment: Thank you very much but in the dev tools i dont have an index page to show code but i have solved this issue by changing the entire fonction